# Suggested edit incorrectly attributed to me

Tags: bug, suggested-edits

There was a [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4073314) that collided with an edit by the OP. The OP had added information to the question, but the suggested edit was missing this, so in the comparison it was like the edit removed this part.

I wanted to approve the suggested edit and also improve it by re-adding the missing part. Meanwhile, the suggested edit had been rejected by 3 people. As a result, the things changed by the suggested edit are now attributed to me.

Either the suggested edit should have been included in the revision history anyway, or it shouldn't be possible for 3 people to reject it while someone else is improving it.

(The question has also been removed now, so it's 10k+ to view it I believe)

Comment: I'm not sure what the question or the problem is. What do you think should have happened?

Comment: @Jerry the problem is that these changes are attributed to me while I didn't make them, and there is no record left of the suggested edit in the revision history. Either the suggested edit should have been included in the revision history anyway, or it shouldn't be possible for 3 people to reject it while someone else is improving it.

Comment: Hmm, what generally happens is that improvement edits are owned by those who make the improvements. What I believe happened is that while you were editing, the suggestion was rejected, which means your improvement edit thus became a simple edit from you. I do support the feature to prevent reviewing a suggested edit while it is being reviewed by 3 others, though I'm not sure if that's possible, or suitable server-side.

Comment: @Jerry That is indeed what happened, like I explained in the question. And I think that's a bug, or at the very least unwanted behaviour.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a bug, but it sure threw me off the first time I did an improvement edit on someone else's suggested edit. In the end though, it does make sense that if you make an improvement edit, you are the owner of the last edit. I guess it could be an unwanted behaviour, but in the end, it wouldn't be fair to blame the one who suggested an edit but that edit was changed by someone else, if there was a problem with the edit.

Comment: @Bart this issue appears to be different than the duplicate you linked.  This is rejected edit/improvement collision and not a grace period issue.

Comment: I see. I'll remove it @psubsee2003, but it's all the same underlying issue afaik.

Comment: @Jerry re: *unfair to blame the one ...* You're aware that normally improving a suggested edit generates two revisions [like here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21244170/revisions)?

Comment: Well, I didn't explicitly say so, but yes, two edits are generated upon issuing an improvement edit. What I meant is that, you made the last edit (improvement edit or not, it's still an edit) and this is what ultimately counts. The suggested edit was just... rejected and didn't make it to the edit history.

Comment: @Bart I don't think it is the same underlying issue.  The question you previously linked is very likely the issue where an edit started within the 5 minute grace period accidentally removes changes made by the OP within the grace period.  This is a rejected edit getting attributed to the improver because it was rejected while he was improving it.